# Why did Mswati III become Crown Prince after his father's death?

Tags: africa, titles, kingdom

I was reading the Wikipedia article for [Mswati III](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mswati_III):

> Mswati was introduced as **crown prince** in September 1983 and was crowned king on 25 April 1986, aged 18 years and 6 days, thus making him one of the youngest reigning monarchs of the late 20th century...

I couldn't open the sources in the references section of the article and with Google search I also didn't find anything.

From [Sobhuza II](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobhuza_II)'s Wikipedia article (Mswati III's father):

> Sobhuza died in 1982, having appointed Prince Sozisa Dlamini to serve as 'Authorized Person', advising a regent. Selection of a successor was confirmed only after King Sobhuza's death, a regent being necessary if the heir remained under age at that time. By tradition, the regent would be one of the queens consort who had borne the late king a son. The first regent was Queen Dzeliwe, but after a power struggle Sozisa deposed her and she was replaced by Queen Ntfombi. During this period Andy Warhol boosted her renown, and that of Swaziland, by including her portrait along with those of Elizabeth II of the Commonwealth Realms, Beatrix of the Netherlands and Margrethe II of Denmark in his Reigning Queens series. Ntombi reigned on behalf of her young son by King Sobhuza, Prince Makhosetive Dlamini, who was designated as **Crown Prince** or Umntfwana. He was crowned King Mswati III in 1986.

**My question**: Why was Mswati III become Crown Prince after his father's death? Isn't Crown Prince/Crown Princess always a title for a Prince/Princess who *is going to be* the future King/Queen after the current Monarch's death? Why didn't the authorities immediately call Mswati III the King after the former King's death? Just like any other kings who have regents before reaching 18.

Comment: It's probably an artifact of attempting to fit European royal titles onto non-European monarchic traditions.

Comment: Agree with KillingTime....  at least to my eye the key assumption in this question is "Isn't Crown Prince/Crown Princess always a title for a Prince/Princess who is going to be the future". How did that culture define the term "crown prince"?

Comment: I think it is answered in the [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mswati_III) article, " When he turned 18 he was called back from his public school in the UK so he could ascend the throne, on 26 April 1986.[10]"  While he was in a foreign country, he was crown prince and his Aunts served as trustees/regents.

Comment: I don't think that's the answer. It just tells us he ascended the throne after he reached the legal age.

Comment: It's true that he was a Crown Prince when he was in a foreign country. But what matters is that he got the title after his father's death, Not in his life.